# AWS No internet when setting up two interfaces in same subnet

Tags: networking, routing, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

I need to setup an elastic network interface (ENI) in AWS which I need to attach to different EC2 instances runing Ubuntu 16.04 from time to time.
I have it set up already and attached it to an EC2 instance.
However, I don't have internet connection as long as it is attached.

My configuration is as follows:

`/etc/network/interfaces.d/50-cloud-init.cfg`:

```bsh
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens5
iface ens5 inet dhcp
```

`/etc/network/interfaces.d/51-secondary.cfg`

```bsh
auto ens6
iface ens6 inet static
    address 172.16.128.10
    netmask 255.255.128.0

# Gateway config
up ip route add default via 172.16.128.1 dev ens6 table 1000

# Routes and rules
up ip route add 172.16.128.10 dev ens6 table 1000
up ip rule add from 172.16.128.10 lookup 1000
```

Output of `ip a`:

```bsh
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:f0:eb:30:e7:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.172.147/17 brd 172.16.255.255 scope global ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f0:ebff:fe30:e7ec/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:16:47:94:ad:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.128.10/17 brd 172.16.255.255 scope global ens6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::16:47ff:fe94:ad7c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output pf `ip r`:

```bsh
default via 172.16.128.1 dev ens5
172.16.128.0/17 dev ens6  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.128.10
172.16.128.0/17 dev ens5  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.172.147
```

I can connect to the instance via SSH on the elastic IP of the secondary network. I can also ping fro this interface (`ping -I ens6 google.de`):

```bsh
PING google.de (172.217.22.99) from 172.16.128.10 ens6: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra15s18-in-f3.1e100.net (172.217.22.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=3.01 ms
64 bytes from fra15s18-in-f3.1e100.net (172.217.22.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=49 time=1.00 ms
```

However, I cannot connect to the internet or ping via the default interface `ens5`. This should be the default gateway though, as this will *always* be attached to the instance.

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue...
The primary interface did not have an elastic IP (or public IP in general) attached to it and could thus not communicate to the internet.